# Ip Subnet Mask, network Devision

Tags: networking, ip, subnet

I' ve been trying all day to find out how to devide a network into 4 networks:

I got the IP: 195.232.176.0 /20

So by converting the IP into the following formation

[octal 1] . [octal 2] . [octal 3] . [octal 4]

11000011 . 11101000 . 10110000 . 00000000

By setting 1 in the first 20bits starting counting from the left I have:

==================20bits==============

11111111 . 11111111 . 1111 0000 . 00000000 = 225.225.240.0 (Subnet Mask)

So the four networks are :

## Starting IP Address: 195.232.176.0 /20

#### 195.232.x.0 /20

#### 195.232.x.0 /20

#### 195.232.x.0 /20

#### 195.232.x.0 /20

Are the 4 networks correct?? My problem is on how will I put the x numbers with the data I have found!

Comment: [This two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) explains IPv4 addressing and subnetting, including a section that specifically covers what you are asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy peasy once you know subnetting.

Let's have a closer look at the IP 195.232.176.0 /20. What is the full range?

```
195.232.176.0 to 195.232.191.255
```

So to divide the **195.232.176.0 /20** up into **4 subnets**, you'll need a **/22** mask for each subnet.

```
195.232.176.0/22 (195.232.176.0 to 195.232.179.255)
195.232.180.0/22 (195.232.180.0 to 195.232.183.255)
195.232.184.0/22 (195.232.184.0 to 195.232.187.255)
195.232.188.0/22 (195.232.188.0 to 195.232.191.255)
```